# jQuery: How to generate random amount of divs with random positions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
var amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101).length; //???

var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "vw";
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "vh";

$('<div></div>').appendTo('html').css({
  "top": x,
  "left": y
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So generally, I would like to generate a random amount of divs with random positions.

Unfortunately, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568818/jquery-slice-random-amount-of-divs) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399643/generate-random-number-of-divs) article doesn't help me. It's too specific.

I would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you mean? (I made them smaller just so you can see the randomness better)

```js
const someRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
const randomColor = () => `#${Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}`

for(i = 0; i <= someRandom(); i++) {
$('<div></div>').appendTo('html').css({
  "top": someRandom() + "vw",
  "left": someRandom() + "vh",
  "background-color": randomColor()
});
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .length in the first line: amount now is some number.

Then loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
   //do the thing with the divs here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9wxy2z3g/ – Did I understand it wrongly?

Comment: You need to do get the random values for x and y inside the loop, otherwise they will just have their first values.